# Integrate Stripe payment method into react JS

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

need help. Now i'm learning to integrate stripe payment method into reactJS. i follow this tutorial [Stripe Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5y5WwF9s-ZI)

because the video uploaded March 2021, some of the code won't work on the current ReactJS version. my ReactJS version is 18.1.0

so i share the code that i build from that tutorial.

file index.JS. i modify for `react-dom` for this file.

```
import React from 'react' 
import App from './App'

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
    <div>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </div>  
);
```

file `App.js` nothing to change. same as the tutorial

```
import {BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm'

const App = () => {
    
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
            <PaymentForm />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
}

export default App;
```

file `index.html` also same as the tutorial

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Stripe app</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="root"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

file `PaymentForm.js` also same as tutorial

```
const PaymentForm = () => {
    return 'Payment Form'
}

export default PaymentForm;
```

the problem is, browser not display anything. From this step... browser should display word `Payment Form`

no error on my tab console. also on my terminal display this message

```
You can now view reactstripe in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.106:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

i'm not sure what is wrong with the code. broswer just display nothing. really empty.

[image: browser empty]

please help

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure as I am new to this myself, but perhaps you need to write return before the jsx in app.js.

I believe the code should look as follows:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm'

const App = () => {
return (
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact>
        <PaymentForm />
    </Route>
</Switch>);
}

export default App;
```

this is because the jsx must be returned in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this will fix your issue, but there are a number of issues with your code. First from my understanding of stripe integration and your `App.js` document should look like this:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm'
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

const App = () => {

const stripePromise = loadStripe(<YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY>);
    
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
           <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
            <PaymentForm />
           </Elements>
        </Route>
    </Switch>
}

export default App;
```

Since all stripes components have to be contained within `<Elements>`

Secondly and most importantly, your screen is blank because you're not returning anything. I'm not sure if you're used to coding in vanilla javascript and not `react`, but in `react` in order to get text on a screen you have to `return( );` with `html` contained within the `return`. So if you're trying to display the words `'Payment Form'` your `PaymentForm.js` should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const PaymentForm = () => {

return (
<div>
Payment Form
</div>
);
}

export default PaymentForm;
```